# Slowness on SQL Server 2008 with Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2008-r2

I am facing a performance problem on our server. The main reason seems the versions of OS and SQL Server. Once I install the SQL Server 2008 on Windows Server 2008 R2, the response time of my web site becomes very slow. Whereas, if I use SQL Server 2008 on another machine which has Windows Storage Server 2003 R2, the response time is much faster.

Both operating systems have the latest updates, do you have any idea of this contradiction? or did anyone experiencing similar problem about new updates to Windows Server 2008 R2 which is running SQL Server 2008?

Thanks,
cas

Comment: Presumably the two servers you mention are identical relative to hardware (memory, CPU, disk configuration)?  By "slow" I assume you mean response time between mouse clicks/ENTER?

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue in the past, with the the same SO and Sql Server version, with a particular DB. My problem was related to the transaction log, i needed to backup/clean it and also needed to free some more space in th drive and after i really could notice the performance going up again.

I don't knwow if by any chance this might be your situation.

HTH!

Answer (score 0):

Do any of the symptoms in  [MS KB918483](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/918483) apply to your situation?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds eerily familiar to what StackOverflow [went through](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/database-upgrade/).  Are you running Dell servers?  We hit the same issue ourselves on new servers running Windows 2008 R2.  The Windows 2003 servers were fine.  Once we updated the BIOS settings on 2008 performance kicked up considerably.

Answer (score 0):

99% of the time the slowdown will have nothing to do with the host OS but something within the database.  Usually the statistics have become stale and the SQL Server isn't generating good execution plans.